# python mechanize brakes the content of TextareaControl

Tags: python, mechanize

I want in admin panel of [OSQA > User Settings] change one checkbox, but when i submit web form with mechanize it shreds content of TextareaControl with additional characters.

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> mech = mechanize.Browser()
>>> mech.open('http://example.com/account/signin/')
>>> mech.select_form(nr=2)
>>> mech["username"] = 'user'
>>> mech["password"] = 'pass'

>>> mech.open('http://example.com/admin/settings/users/')
>>> for el in mech.forms():
...     print el
... 
<POST http://example.com/admin/settings/users/ multipart/form-data
  <HiddenControl(csrfmiddlewaretoken=XxWchtzV5oR6ezkObhnk4nzIemTc8aDC) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH=3)>
  <TextareaControl(RESERVED_USERNAMES=testing, this)>  # << HERE
  <CheckboxControl(TRUNCATE_LONG_USERNAMES=[*on])>
  <CheckboxControl(SHOW_USER_ACCEPT_RATE=[*on])>
  <TextControl(FREEZE_ACCEPT_RATE_FOR=admin)>
  <SubmitControl(submit=Save) (readonly)>>

>>> mech.select_form(nr=0)
>>> print mech["RESERVED_USERNAMES"]
... testing, this
```

So when i submit it now without even modifying any field ...

```
>>> results = mech.submit()
```

... the content of TextareaControl becomes:

```
>>> mech.open('http://example.com/admin/settings/users/')
>>> mech.select_form(nr=0)
>>> print mech["RESERVED_USERNAMES"]
... t, ,,  , e, ,,  , s, ,,  , t, ,,  , i, ,,  , n, ,,  , g, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , t, ,,  , h, ,,  , i, ,,  , s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying to debug mechanize but with no luck.

I ended up with selecting those checkboxes by changing OSQA settings before installation in `osqa/forum/settings/users.py`

```
REQUIRE_EMAIL_VALIDATION_TO = Setting('REQUIRE_EMAIL_VALIDATION_TO', [], USERS_SET, dict(
label = _("Require email validation to..."),
help_text = _("Which actions in this site, users without a valid email will be prevented from doing."),
widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":"checked"}),
choices=(("ask", _("ask questions")), ("answer", _("provide answers")), ("comment", _("make comments")), ("flag", _("report posts"))),
required=False,
))
```

Added `(attrs={"checked":"checked"})`, this is not what I was going up to but solves my problem.